# react npm run build returns webpack>5 issue

Tags: reactjs, webpack, mern

Hi everyone I was running my react code using npm run build and i did not change my code and SUDDENLY I get this error. I tried ALL 3 solutions here and nothing works. This is so dumb. https://namespaceit.com/blog/how-fix-breaking-change-webpack-5-used-to-include-polyfills-for-nodejs-core-modules-by-default-error